# Quiero reproducir un audio en JS y HTML depende de la cantidad de respuestas correctas pero no sé cómo hacerlo

Tags: javascript, html, audio

No logro hacer que se reproduzca el audio lo que trato de hacer esque si sacas entre 3 respuestas buenas se reproduciera el audio1 (meh.mp3), si contestas todas correctas reproducir el audio2 (win.mp3) y si contestas todas malas reproducir el audio3 (lose.mp3) pero aún no sé cómo hacerlo

Aquí el código del index

---

Cuestionario Del Pelon!

## Cuestionario Escolar!

```
Pregunta 1
```

Cual es el primer nombre del profesor?

Pregunta 2

Como Se guarda un archivo PHP?

.JS
 .php

Pregunta 3

Como se hace una seria de numeros random (función)?

rand
 var

Pregunta 4

Como se cierra un cuerpo en php?

var xd
con la función echo

Pregunta 5

Que Aplicacion Se uso Para Hacer El Codigo En El Aula?

Blog De Notas
Xampp

Pregunta 6

Que Aplicacion Se uso Para Hacer El Servidor Local En El Aula?

Blog De Notas
Xampp

---

### Y AQUI EL CODIGO DEL MAIN DONDE GUARDO LOS DATOS

function check(){   var question1 = document.quiz.question1.value;  var question2 = document.quiz.question2.value;  var question3 = document.quiz.question3.value;var question4 = document.quiz.question4.value;
var question5=
document.quiz.question5.value;
var question6=
document.quiz.question6.value;

```
var correct = 0;    if (question1 == "Hipolito") {      correct++;} if (question2 == ".php") {      correct++;}     if (question3 == "rand") {      correct++;  }   
if(question4 == "echo"){ correct++;}
if(question5 == "BlogNotas"){ correct++;}
if(question6 == "Xampp"){ correct++;}

var sounds = ["img/win.mp3", "img/meh.mp3","img/lose.mp3"];


    var pictures = ["img/win.gif","img/meh.gif", "img/lose.gif"];
        var messages = ["Bien Wey!", "Mejor no hubieras hecho nada", "Tu Realmente Necesitas Ayuda Psicologica"];   var score;  if (correct == 0) {     score = 2;  }   if (correct > 0 && correct < 6) {       score = 1;  }   if (correct == 6) {     score = 0;  }   document.getElementById("after_submit").style.visibility = "visible";   document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = messages[score]; document.getElementById("number_correct").innerHTML = "Tu Respondiste Bien " + correct + " correct.";   document.getElementById("picture").src = pictures[score];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Añadir un tag audio al DOM

```
<audio id="sound"></audio>
```

Y este es el js:

```
var soundContainer = document.getElementById("sound")
soundContainer.src = sounds[score];
soundContainer.play();
```

Parece un ejercicio de clase de programación. Mucha suerte!.
Ojalá en el futuro volvieras a hacer este ejercicio... te darías cuenta de cuánto habrás mejorado!
Dale duro!